Error when I try run celery to run my dash python app
When I run the command "celery -A app.gryphon_ui.celery_app worker -l info -P eventlet", I receive this error. I tried to re-install celery and importlib.metadata, but it did not help. The problem is, there is no address of error in my code. All the errors are in the site-packages. However, my packages was working well before. When I imported a class (written by me) to my code to process the data in my app, I received this error. The class is also working well outside this app.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\code\gryphon-ui\.venv\Scripts\celery.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "c:\code\gryphon-ui\.venv\lib\site-packages\celery\__main__.py", line 15, in main
    sys.exit(_main())
  File "c:\code\gryphon-ui\.venv\lib\site-packages\celery\bin\celery.py", line 235, in main
    return celery(auto_envvar_prefix="CELERY")
  File "c:\code\gryphon-ui\.venv\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1157, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\code\gryphon-ui\.venv\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1078, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "c:\code\gryphon-ui\.venv\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1688, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "c:\code\gryphon-ui\.venv\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1434, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "c:\code\gryphon-ui\.venv\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 783, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\code\gryphon-ui\.venv\lib\site-packages\click\decorators.py", line 34, in new_func
    return f(get_current_context(), *args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\code\gryphon-ui\.venv\lib\site-packages\celery\bin\base.py", line 134, in caller
    return f(ctx, *args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\code\gryphon-ui\.venv\lib\site-packages\celery\bin\worker.py", line 348, in worker
    worker = app.Worker(
  File "c:\code\gryphon-ui\.venv\lib\site-packages\celery\worker\worker.py", line 98, in __init__
    self.setup_instance(**self.prepare_args(**kwargs))
  File "c:\code\gryphon-ui\.venv\lib\site-packages\celery\worker\worker.py", line 138, in setup_instance
    self.blueprint.apply(self, **kwargs)
  File "c:\code\gryphon-ui\.venv\lib\site-packages\celery\bootsteps.py", line 211, in apply
    step.include(parent)
  File "c:\code\gryphon-ui\.venv\lib\site-packages\celery\bootsteps.py", line 379, in include
    inc, ret = self._should_include(parent)
  File "c:\code\gryphon-ui\.venv\lib\site-packages\celery\bootsteps.py", line 335, in _should_include
    return True, self.create(parent)
  File "c:\code\gryphon-ui\.venv\lib\site-packages\celery\worker\components.py", line 225, in create
    c = w.consumer = self.instantiate(
  File "c:\code\gryphon-ui\.venv\lib\site-packages\celery\bootsteps.py", line 331, in instantiate
    return instantiate(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\code\gryphon-ui\.venv\lib\site-packages\celery\utils\imports.py", line 48, in instantiate
    return symbol_by_name(name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\code\gryphon-ui\.venv\lib\site-packages\celery\worker\consumer\consumer.py", line 233, in __init__
    self.blueprint.apply(self, **dict(worker_options or {}, **kwargs))
  File "c:\code\gryphon-ui\.venv\lib\site-packages\celery\bootsteps.py", line 205, in apply
    step = S(parent, **kwargs)
  File "c:\code\gryphon-ui\.venv\lib\site-packages\celery\worker\consumer\control.py", line 25, in __init__
    self.box = (pidbox.gPidbox if self.is_green else pidbox.Pidbox)(c)
  File "c:\code\gryphon-ui\.venv\lib\site-packages\celery\worker\pidbox.py", line 28, in __init__
    self.node = c.app.control.mailbox.Node(
  File "c:\code\gryphon-ui\.venv\lib\site-packages\kombu\utils\objects.py", line 32, in __get__
    return super().__get__(instance, owner)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\functools.py", line 981, in __get__
    val = self.func(instance)
  File "c:\code\gryphon-ui\.venv\lib\site-packages\celery\app\base.py", line 1310, in control
    return instantiate(self.control_cls, app=self)
  File "c:\code\gryphon-ui\.venv\lib\site-packages\celery\utils\imports.py", line 48, in instantiate
    return symbol_by_name(name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\code\gryphon-ui\.venv\lib\site-packages\kombu\utils\imports.py", line 59, in symbol_by_name
    module = imp(module_name, package=package, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "c:\code\gryphon-ui\.venv\lib\site-packages\celery\app\control.py", line 17, in <module>
    from kombu.matcher import match
  File "c:\code\gryphon-ui\.venv\lib\site-packages\kombu\matcher.py", line 143, in <module>
    for ep, args in entrypoints('kombu.matchers'):
  File "c:\code\gryphon-ui\.venv\lib\site-packages\kombu\utils\compat.py", line 77, in entrypoints
    entry_points = importlib_metadata.entry_points(group=namespace)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\importlib\metadata\__init__.py", line 1009, in entry_points
    return SelectableGroups.load(eps).select(**params)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\importlib\metadata\__init__.py", line 459, in load
    ordered = sorted(eps, key=by_group)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\importlib\metadata\__init__.py", line 1006, in <genexpr>
    eps = itertools.chain.from_iterable(
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\importlib\metadata\_itertools.py", line 15, in unique_everseen
    for element in iterable:
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\importlib\metadata\__init__.py", line 904, in <genexpr>
    path.search(prepared) for path in map(FastPath, paths)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\importlib\metadata\__init__.py", line 802, in search
    return self.lookup(self.mtime).search(name)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\importlib\metadata\__init__.py", line 807, in mtime
    return os.stat(self.root).st_mtime
TypeError: stat: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or integer, not NoneType

Could you please tell me the source of this error and the way I can solve it?
